# Transforming one row into many rows using Amazon Glue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, aws-glue

I'm trying to use Amazon Glue to turn one row into many rows. My goal is something like a SQL UNPIVOT.

I have a pipe delimited text file that is 360GB, compressed (gzip). It has over 1,620 columns. Here's the basic layout:

```
primary_key|property1_name|property1_value|property800_name|property800_value
12345|is_male|1|is_college_educated|1
```

There are over 800 of these property name/value fields. There are roughly 280 million rows. The file is in an S3 bucket. I need to get the data into Redshift, but the column limit in Redshift is 1,600.

The users want me to unpivot the data. For example:

```
primary_key|key|value
12345|is_male|1
12345|is_college_educated|1
```

I believe I can use Amazon Glue for this. But, this is my first time using Glue. I'm struggling to figure out a good way to do this. Some of the pySpark-extension Transformations look promising (perhaps, "Map" or "Relationalize"). see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-etl-scripts-pyspark-transforms.html. 
So, my question is: What is a good way to do this in Glue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AWS Glue does not have an appropriate built-in `GlueTransform` subclass to convert single `DynamicRecord` into multiple (as usual MapReduce mapper can do). You either cannot create such a transform yourself.

But there are two ways to solve your problem.

## Option 1: Using Spark RDD API

Let's try to perform exactly what you need: map single record to multiple ones. Because of `GlueTransform` limitations we will have to dive deeper and use Spark RDD API.

RDD has special [`flatMap`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.flatMap) method which allows to produce multiple `Row`'s which are then flattened. The code for your example will look something like this:

```py
source_data = somehow_get_the_data_into_glue_dynamic_frame()
source_data_rdd = source_data.toDF().rdd
unpivoted_data_rdd = source_data_rdd.flatMap(
    lambda row: (
        (
            row.id,
            getattr(row, f'{field}_name'),
            getattr(row, f'{field}_value'),
        )
        for field in properties_names
    ),
)
unpivoted_data = glue_ctx.create_dynamic_frame \
    .from_rdd(unpivoted_data_rdd, name='unpivoted')
```

## Option 2: Map + Relationalize + Join

If you want to do the requested operation using only AWS Glue ETL API then here are my instructions:

1. First [map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html) every single `DynamicRecord` from source into primary key and list of objects:

```py
mapped = Map.apply(
    source_data,
    lambda record:  # here we operate on DynamicRecords not RDD Rows
        DynamicRecord(
            primary_key=record.primary_key,
            fields=[
                dict(
                    key=getattr(row, f'{field}_name'),
                    value=getattr(row, f'{field}_value'),
                )
                for field in properties_names
            ],
        )
)
```

Example input:

```
primary_key|property1_name|property1_value|property800_name|property800_value
      12345|is_male       |              1|is_new          |                1
      67890|is_male       |              0|is_new          |                0
```

Output:

```
primary_key|fields
      12345|[{'key': 'is_male', 'value': 1}, {'key': 'is_new', 'value': 1}]
      67890|[{'key': 'is_male', 'value': 0}, {'key': 'is_new', 'value': 0}]
```

2. Next [relationalize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-Relationalize.html) it: every list will be converted into multiple of rows, every nested object will be unnested ([Scala Glue ETL API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-dynamicframe-class.html#glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-dynamicframe-class-defs-relationalize) have good examples and more detailed explanations than Python docs).

```
relationalized_dfc = Relationalize.apply(
    mapped,
    staging_path='s3://tmp-bucket/tmp-dir/',  # choose any dir for temp files
)
```

The method returns `DynamicFrameCollection`. In case of single array field it will contain two `DynamicFrame`'s: first with `primary_key` and foreign key to flattened and unnested `fields` dynamic frame.
Output:

```
# table name: roottable
primary_key|fields
      12345|     1
      67890|     2
```

```
# table name: roottable.fields
id|index|val.key|val.value
 1|    0|is_male|        1
 1|    1|is_new |        1
 2|    0|is_male|        0
 2|    1|is_new |        0
```

3. The last logical step is to join these two `DynamicFrame`'s:

```py
joined = Join.apply(
    frame1=relationalized_dfc['roottable'],
    keys1=['fields'],
    frame2=relationalized_dfc['roottable.fields'],
    keys2=['id'],
)
```

Output:

```
primary_key|fields|id|index|val.key|val.value
      12345|     1| 1|    0|is_male|        1
      12345|     1| 1|    1|is_new |        1
      67890|     2| 2|    0|is_male|        0
      67890|     2| 2|    1|is_new |        0
```

Now you just have to [rename](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-RenameField.html) and [select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-SelectFields.html) the desired fields.